# Delete a Tenant in WSO2 API Manager 1.7.0

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possibile to delete a Tenant in WSO2 API Manager 1.7.0 ?

How can this be done ?

Deactivating the Tenant is not enough for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this through any of the WSO2 Product's admin service  API called `RemoteTenantManagerService`. There is an operation named `deleteTenant`.

1. Enable admin services by changing the value to true for

   ```
   <HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
   ```
2. Start the APIM
3. Use the webservice provided through https://abimaran:9443/services/RemoteTenantManagerService?wsdl
4. There is an opration named `deleteTenant`. You can provide the tenant id to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, in a perfect world, these Admin Services would be named the same on every WSO2 product. However, we do not live in a perfect world and they are not always named the same. For instance, the Tenant Admin service on the ESB 4.9.0 is called "TenantMgtAdminService" vs. "RemoteTenantManagerService".

You should always refer to the individual product's instructions on enabling the AdminServices WSDLs in the carbon.xml file, then start the product with the osgi Console using the wso2carbon.bat/.sh switch -DosgiConsole and then enter "listAdminServices" to find the name of the tenant management admin service for that particular WSO2 product.